# OK to use random FK ID in FactoryBot definition when FK associated object is not an AR relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, factory-bot

I've often heard not to use random data when writing tests, which seems reasonable for most data.

However, I think I have a case where it might be necessary. The code I'm working on has a few non-AR models. For instance, the User model is not backed by a DB table, because we pull these records in via API.

Other AR-backed models are "associated" to the non-AR User model via FKs, but they are not AR assocations. Therefore, I can't just make an implicit association in FactoryBot with `owner`, I have to manually set the `owner_id` attribute.

This is currently being done via `sequence(:owner_id)` like so...

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :dog do
    sequence(:owner_id)
    name "Sparky"
    legs 4
   end
  end
end
```

The problem is, since multiple factories manually set the `owner_id` FK using sequence, but FactoryBot does not know they are referencing the same model, the sequences are not incremented in tandem.

Thus, there are intermittent specs when the above `dog` factory `user_id` is `1` and another factory has set the `user_id` to `1` as well. This makes the data appear to be associated when it should not be **which is the fundamental reason why some specs are failing intermittently** - data appears to be related when it should not be (because of inadvertently aligned FKs).

While I think this certainly sounds like a bigger design issue, I'm trying to find a quick fix since lots of existing specs depend on the current design and I don't have time to do all that refactoring.

So, that's why I want to do the following:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :dog do
    owner_id { rand(1_000_000) }
    name "Sparky"
    legs 4
   end
  end
end
```

I know this doesn't ensure uniqueness, but I do think it will make the intermittent specs that fail only occasionally now basically disappear.

*FYI: This question has been updated significantly since some answers came in, thank you all for the responses, sorry if the updated question takes some of the existng answers out of context a bit :(*

Comment: FactoryGirl/FactoryBot will generate an id for you when you create a new object. I would not specify any id at all. Just let the database handle it for you. That's also the closest approximation of object creation in production.

Comment: BECAUSE, `rand(100_000)` doesn't guarantee that it will be unique every time. Most of the times, but not always. And ID should always be unique. Leave its handling to the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple counter example - you try to create two dogs. It just so happens that the dice roll the same number. Your spec now fails due to `id` not being unique.

Also, generally speaking, I don't expect you to be setting `id`s when you create records. You most probably have them on auto increment.

---

If you are using randomness just so that certain values for each record differ, you can instead use sequences:

```
sequence(:name) { |n| "Sparky No#{n}" }
```

Comment: flaky specs are the worst :/

Comment: Time-based specs which only break once a month/year (or at specific time of day) are second worst :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, technically, I consider specs that break based on time flaky as well.

Comment: They certainly are, but they are less worse in the sense that we can reasonably guess the origin of the random failures. Sometimes. :)